# class not getting initialised on server startup

Tags: tomcat, web.xml

I Want to call the following class when the server starts up.

AlertsData is in com.mongo.service:

```
public  class AlertsData extends HttpServlet{
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
        alertingPoolsData();
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AlertsData</servlet-name>
    <display-name>AlertsData</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mongo.service.AlertsData</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet-mapping>
```

getting folloiwng error:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/lbmongo]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

With this server is not starting up and getting follwoing error..some one please help :(
   I Want to call a AlertsData class when the server starts up.

Comment: what does alteringPoolsData() do actually?

Comment: That is not the full error message. There will be much more explaining why the Context failed to start.

Comment: Full error message:  alertingPoolsData calls mongoDB every 5 seconds:

Comment: alertingPoolsData calls mongoDM every 5 seconds: COmplete error is below:

:Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/lbmongo]]


 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name AlertsData
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3213)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name AlertsData
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3213)

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet config in `web.xml` looks invalid. Elements like `servlet-class` and `load-on-startup` belong to the `servlet` section, not the `servlet-mapping` section. You should have both a `servlet` section and a `servlet-mapping` section, e.g.:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AlertsData</servlet-name>
    <display-name>AlertsData</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mongo.service.AlertsData</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AlertsData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/alerts</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `url-pattern` under `sevlet-mapping` is the URL you want to use to access the servlet (replace "`/alerts`" by your own URL).